# Complexity of finding the square root of a perfect square

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

What is the complexity of precisely finding the square root of a perfect square?

Comment: Of course there is an algorithm: How would you solve the problem yourself with an infinite supply or paper and pencils?

Comment: I removed the part of the question which asks whether there is an algorithm to compute the square root of a perfect square at all, because that part is too elementary for this website.  Please read [How to ask a good question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and in particular [Understand what you really want to ask](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question/307#307).

Answer (score 9):

The square root of an $n$-digit number can be computed in time $O(M(n))$ using e.g. Newton’s iteration, where $M(n)$ is the time needed to multiply two $n$-digit integers. The current best bound on $M(n)$ is $n\log n\,2^{O(\log^*n)}$, provided by Fürer’s algorithm. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots for more square root algorithms, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations for an overview of computational complexity of arithmetical operations.

Comment: Does finding square root have $NC$ algorithm?

Comment: In particular is testing perfect square in $NC$?

Comment: Yes, square roots can be in fact computed in uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$.

Comment: is this the reference (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5f8b/d44c0a27627be872b912e5b526deea0f9b95.pdf)?

Comment: I'm not interested in downloading pdfs from random URLs. What is the author and title of the paper that you are asking about?

Comment: I should have said 'is this a good reference?'. I am wondering if there is a good reference.

Comment: I'm not in the office to check it, but it is very likely mentioned in the paper by Hesse, Allender, and Barrington where they prove that division and iterated multiplication are uniform TC^0.

Comment: I looked there I am unable to find the result you mention there.

Comment: It’s the last item in Corollary 6.5.

Comment: May I ask if 'Given 0<a<b find a perfect square in [a,b]' is also in TC0 (would that be functional version of TC0?)?

Comment: Yes, this is also in $\mathrm{TC}^0$ (or more precisely, $\mathrm{FTC}^0$): “output $\lfloor\sqrt b\rfloor^2$ if it is $\ge a$, otherwise there is no solution”.

Comment: P consists of decision problems. Linear programming (in the form relevant here) is a decision problem. Any problem in P reduces to linear programming, that means decision problems. Computing perfect squares in $[a,b]$ is a search problem, not a decision problem, so the reduction to linear programming does not apply. (I have no idea how any of this has anything to do with NC or TC0.)

Comment: So there is a linear program $L(a,b)$ that depends only on $a,b$ that outputs $1$ iff input integer $c$ is in $[a,b]$ and is a perfect square? Since the testing squares and testing membership in $[a,b]$ are in $TC0$ can we expect only logarithmic number of variables and constraints in the linear program and so this particular linear program can be solved in $TC0$. I have some further queries which can I email you?

Comment: I can’t say I understand what you wrote. [Linear programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) don’t have any notion of “input” separate from the program itself. The P-completeness of LP means that there is a (easily computable) function $L(a,b)$ that gives a linear program such that $L(a,b)$ is feasible iff there is a perfect square in $[a,b]$. I likewise don’t know why would you think you only need logarithmic number of variables. The construction of $L(a,b)$ that I know makes the number of variables the size of a circuit that computes the original problem, which will be ...

Comment: ... polynomial in the size of the original input $a,b$. Concerning your last question, I’m sorry, but I am busy, and not interested in answering elementary questions by email. You should ask your tutor. Or at http://cs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: thank you...,... $TC0$ is in $L$ that is why I thought. Actually I do not have any further queries along this line since I was thinking something else.

Comment: Given, a perfect square, I think the binary search algorithm is sufficient to determine the square root. This has time complexity of $\mathcal{O}{(log\ n)}$

Comment: @Joker First, $n$ is not the input number itself, but the number of its digits. Thus binary search takes $O(n)$ multiplications rather than $O(\log n)$. Second, each of these multiplications takes about $M(n)$ steps, rather than $O(1)$ as you seem to assume. Thus, the binary search algorithm takes $O(M(n)n)$ steps, which is much worse than other methods.

Comment: For the record, if you count the number of multiplications instead of the full complexity, Newton iteration is still much more efficient than binary search, as it takes $O(\log n)$ multiplications, whereas binary search takes $O(n)$, as already mentioned.